# Hibernate Query - Entities that are NOT a child entity of another entity

Tags: hibernate, criteria, psql

I have a somehow recursive structure of entities: The entity `Goal` has a property `subgoals` which is a list of `Goal` entities themselves.

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "GOAL" )
public class Goal {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "goal_subgoals")
    private List<Goal> subgoals = new ArrayList<Goal>();
    ...
}
```

Now I need a query that gets *all* `Goal` entities which *are not* a `subgoal` of any `Goal`.

Since there is a join table `goal_subgoals`, with columns `goal_id` and `subgoals_id`, maybe what I need is all goals whose `id` is not in the `subgoals_id` column of that table. Any suggestion on how to do this?

I know how to get all Goals that are subgoals:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
            "SELECT subgoalx "
                    +" FROM Goal goalx "
                    + "JOIN goalx.subgoals subgoalx "                       
            );
```

Is there a way to get the complement of that set?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me

```
    DetachedCriteria subQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Goal.class,"goalx")
            .createAlias("goalx.subgoals", "subgoalsx")
            .setProjection(Projections.property("subgoalsx.id"));

    Criteria query = session.createCriteria(Goal.class)
            .add(Subqueries.propertyNotIn("id",subQuery));
```